# Advantage of generic base class

Tags: c#, generics

What's the advantage of having a generic base class and a derived class having itself as the generic parameter on the base class.

e.g.

```
public abstract class MyBase<T> {}
public MyDerived : MyBase<MyDerived> {}
```

Comment: Have a look for CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern). I wasn't aware that this works in C# as well, but it seems it does (more or less): http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/09/27/crtp-in-c/

Comment: This particular example has NO Advantages.  Why? because MyBase adds no value.  It's a hollowed out container for MyDervied and serves no additional purpose other than to attach a new Name to MyDerivied.  The problem with this will be later on when users of MyBase have to use reflection to figure out what type of MyBase it is......  Think about containment instead.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs all. I didn't know there was a pattern related to this kind of construct. I've done reading on CRTP and eric lipperts blog and they've been insightful.

Comment: @JohannesS. link should be http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/09/27/crtp-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage compared to what? I interpret your question as: "in which situation does such a construct make sense?". I found a standard example [in Eric Lippert's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116064011/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx). Replace `MyBase` by `IComparable` (it does not really matter if the latter is an abstract class or an interface), this leads to

```
public MyDerived : IComparable<MyDerived> {}
```

which simply means: "`MyDerived` objects can be compared with other objects of type `MyDerived`" - a simple, not very special situation, which I guess will not need any deeper explanation.

More general: whenever you can think of a meaningful method in a class which takes a second object of that same class (or can return a second object of that class), you have a candidate for your scenario. When this method seems to be generic, and you decide to refactor this method to an abstract base class, this will straightforward lead to the construct.

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely off here, but I'd say the big thing here is the fact that this allows you to share one abstract code base/interface between all your derived classes, but at the same time you prevent them from being directly related, i.e. you prevent the usage of the base class to make a reference pointing to objects of any derived class.

Answer (score 1):

The same advantage of any base class: **code reuse**.

Why would I duplicate code that could be shared across multiple implementations of a generic base class?

The reason why you would have any concrete implementations that inherit from the generic base would be if you wanted to add specific functionality for that concrete type.  (or to have an abstract function in the base that is implemented differently across concrete implementations)